# How send data from action method to view in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Expression in view 
i have model in mvc name Flight :

```
 public class Flight
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "name is required")]
    [StringLength(170)]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "flight company is required")]
    [DisplayName("company Name")]
    public string flightCompany { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int idAvaribleClass { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Duration TO")]
    public string flightDuration { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Ariport Name")]
     [StringLength(200)]
    public string airportName { get; set; } 
    public int idRegisterFlght { get; set; }
    public List<FlightDuration> FlightDurations { get; set; }
    public List<AvalibleClass> AvalibleClasses { get; set; }
    public List<registerFlightProgram> registerFlightPrograms { get; set; }




}
```

i have action method which search in database about what is user enter in view and return two table by query linq.i want show this table in view    :

_Mydb _db = new _Mydb();

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = null, string to = null)
    {
        var q =
          (from c in _db.flights
           join p in _db.Durations on c.id equals p.FlightId
           where (p.to == to) && (p.fromStar == searchTerm) && (to != null)
           select new
           {
               c = new Flight { id = c.id, name = c.name, flightCompany = c.flightCompany, date = c.date, idAvaribleClass = c.idAvaribleClass, flightDuration = c.flightDuration, airportName = c.airportName, idRegisterFlght = c.idRegisterFlght },
               p = new FlightDuration { id = p.id, fromStar = p.fromStar, to = p.to, takeOffTime = p.takeOffTime, expectedTime = p.expectedTime, priceDuration = p.priceDuration, FlightId =p.FlightId}
           }).SingleOrDefault();

        return View(q);
    }

 *code view , expression in "@foreach"*   



 @model IEnumerable<TourismPro.Models.Flight>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()){
<form method="post">
    <input type="search" name="searchTerm" />
     <input type="search" name="to" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search By Name" />

    **@foreach (var item in Model)**
{
    <div>
    @item.flightCompany
        </div>
}
</form>
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Anyway, you view is strongly typed to `@model IEnumerable<TourismPro.Models.Flight>` and you are returning single object using `SingileorDefault()` which won't work.

Comment: i want return object : this object is  result linq (join between two table)  "Flight" and "duration" but when i want read result in View in           Foreach (show Exposition)